# jenkins declarative syntax to connect to remote ubuntu machine

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I have to write a declarative Jenkins pipeline which will be able to

1. ssh into remote ubuntu VM's launched through Ansible tower
2. switch to sudo user
3. run a few scripts

But I'm unable to establish connectivity to the ubuntu machine.

I referred to  https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-steps-plugin
assuming the password to be provided while configuring the credentials (while creating credentialsId) is the password of my ubuntu machine.

Could you verify what could go wrong?

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage ('SSH') {
            steps {
                script{
                    remote = [:]
                    remote.name = "xxxx"
                    remote.host = "xxxx"
                    remote.allowAnyHosts = true
                    remote.failOnError = true
                    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'xxxx', passwordVariable: 'password', usernameVariable: 'username')]) {
                        remote.user = username
                        remote.password = password
                        sshCommand remote: remote, command: "ls -l"
                    }
                }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you are "unable to establish connectivity", what actually fails? Are you getting an error message? What does it say?

Comment: [java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)]] error